# logstash startup issue

Tags: java, linux, logstash

I am reading at http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/faster-startup-time/

I did unzip jar and trying to run but i don't know what i am doing wrong?

```
#unzip logstash-1.1.5-monolithic.jar -d  dest_dir
#java -jar -cp /past/to/extracted/logstash/dest_dir logstash.runner agent -f /path/to/logstash/config.conf -- web --backend elasticsearch:///?local
Unable to access jarfile logstash.runner
```

Comment: get rid of the `-jar` switch - you're attempting to run a class not a `.jar` file.

Comment: Thansk! it works! but now i am getting strange errors Grok::PatternError: pattern %{IPORHOST:device} not defined...compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok-pure.rb:131
             loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1410
          compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok-pure.rb:91
          compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok/pure/pile.rb:51
         register at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/filters/grok.rb:142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster startup time can now be achieved by using the flatjar. This jar packs logstash differently so that ruby doesn't have to scan so many paths at startup, thus reducing startup time. This is easier than unziping the jar and it is comparable in startup time.

[Using FlatJar](http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/faster-startup-time/)

Answer (score 0):

You might've hit this issue if you are using the embedded "web" mode - 
https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1316?focusedCommentId=20134&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-20134